# Autowired ServletContext is NULL in bean defined by xml

Tags: java, spring, autowired

In my spring MVC application I am creating a bean in root-context.xml

```
<bean class="com.app.commons.utilities.AppInfoHelper"
        init-method="setApplicationInfo" lazy-init="false">         
</bean>
```

In AppInfoHelper.java I want to use `ServletContext` for some business logic, so I used `@Autowired` in that class as follows:

```
public final class AppInfoHelper 
{
    public static ApplicationInfo appInfo=null;
    private AppInfoHelper() {}
    
    @Autowired
    ServletContext servletContext;
    
    public void setApplicationInfo() 
    {
        if(servletContext.getAttribute("appNOTRegistered") != null)
        {
            //some logic here
        }            
    }   
}
```

As `setApplicationInfo` is init-method for the bean so when I check `servletContext` in the method it's always NULL. I checked that `component-scan` is correctly set as `<context:component-scan base-package="com.app.*" />` also `<annotation-driven />` is also their in servlet-context.xml file.

What I am doing wrong?

My web.xml is as follows:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ServletContext` is not a Spring bean and it can, therefore, not be injected unless you implement `ServletContextAware`.

```
@Controller
public class ServicesImpl implements Services, ServletContextAware{

@Autowired
private ServletContext context;

public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
     this.context = servletContext;
}
```

Comment: So you mean to say I have to implement `ServletContextAware` into my `AppInfoHelper` class.

Comment: Yes you need to implement ServletContextAware into AppInfoHelper class. It should help

Comment: May be you are right (I haven't tried your solution), but I found a different solution. Please check in answer.

Answer (score 0):

While trying to find the cause, I realized small mistake and hence found a solution.

As I said I was creating bean of class `AppInfoHelper` in root-context.xml which a configuration file of `ContextLoaderListener`, which creates root application context. According to root and chile contexts :

- Root context cannot access child contexts beans

Here, `ServletContext` is created by `DispatcherServlet` which a child context and hence it is not accessible (directly) by the bean created in root context.

**Solution:**

I removed following bean creation from root-context.xml and added into servlet-context.xml.

```
<bean class="com.app.commons.utilities.AppInfoHelper"
        init-method="setApplicationInfo" lazy-init="false">         
</bean>
```

By this change, `ServletContext` is auto wired in bean.

ref:
https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-mvc/contextloaderlistener-vs-dispatcherservlet/